# Resize/reload of Masonry container not firing after click

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, masonry

I've spent hours trying to troubleshoot this without avail, including reloadItems, reinitializing Masonry completely on click, and about 100 other things I've found on StackOverflow. Basically, I have a button that hides a sidebar and when clicked, I'd like the Masonry container to automatically refresh and expand to 3 columns. Currently it works if you resize the window, but not on initial click. Additionally, when you resize the window and click the button to show the sidebar again, the layout overlaps. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Masonry
    $('.grid').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
        gutter: '.gutter-sizer',
        percentPosition: true,
        horizontalOrder: true
    });

    // Sidebar
    $('button').on('click', function(){
        $('#primary').toggleClass('closed');
        $('#secondary').toggleClass('closed');
    });
});
```

Here's a Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QQmjRW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reload the masonry container you can use `$('.grid').masonry();` on your click event.

Your transitions are preventing masonry from getting the right values on click. So why not use the build in transition for masonry? Just add `transitionDuration: '0.2s'` to the masonry options.

Also, you're trying to make the masonry container expand over the full width of the page. The width attribute from `#primary.closed` is preventing this. By changing it to flex-basis, it will change from 66% to 100% when `.closed` is added on click.

Check this CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ddmMQM

Comment: Doh! Thank you so much.. so simple.